# How to clear values in columns of a dataframe in pandas if there are no values in another dataframe with the same index an column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with same index and column names.

In one dataframe I have time series of equity prices. In the other one I have the rolling sum of these equity returns.

The problem that I have now is that in the dataframe with the rolling sum there are still values even when there are no equity prices at that time.

So if the equity left the portfolio on January the 2nd for example, I will have ongoing rolling sums for 10 more days, if 10 was my period value.

I want to clear those 10 more fields in the rolling sum dataframe. So that the rolling sum time series stops at the date similar to the time series of the equity prices.

These are two columns

| Index | Stock A |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-10 | 23 |
| 2022-12-11 | 25 |
| 2022-12-12 | 21 |
| 2022-12-13 |  |
| 2022-12-14 |  |
| 2022-12-15 |  |

| Index | Rolling sum |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-10 | 0,54 |
| 2022-12-11 | 0,55 |
| 2022-12-12 | 0,51 |
| 2022-12-13 | 0,49 |
| 2022-12-14 | 0,48 |
| 2022-12-15 | 0,47 |

this is how it should look like

| Index | Rolling sum |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-10 | 0,54 |
| 2022-12-11 | 0,55 |
| 2022-12-12 | 0,51 |
| 2022-12-13 |  |
| 2022-12-14 |  |
| 2022-12-15 |  |

let df be my equity dataframe.
let df1 be my dataframe with the rolling sums.

I tried to replace the empty fields in df with fillna(0) and change the dataframe to a bool. Then replace all 0 fields with False. Then compare to df2 but the fields in df2 didn't change.

```
df = df .fillna(0)
df_bool = df.copy()                                 
df_bool = df_bool.astype(bool) 
df_bool .replace(False, pd.NA, inplace=False)

df2.where(df_bool , False).reset_index()
```

I don't know where I made an error or if there is a smarter solution. For sure there will be one.
short said....if a field in df is empty it should also be empty in df2 without changing the other existing values in in df2.

Edit:This is just an example. I have a few hundred columns of stock data in the dataframes that have to be cleared that way. so i think the solution should consider the whole dataframe.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEctQ.jpg)
[image]

the picture in the link are the stock prices
yello is the difference that should be empty in the rolling sum example

Comment: Hi, while I do not have the full context of where you are going with this, from my point of view, it seems you made life difficult with your structure choice. Could we use a single table(Index, StockA, Rolling sum) instead? Also, why keep the last indices (2022-12-13, 2022-12-14 and 2022-12-15) if the data they are supposed to be a key for is NULL?
@SomeDude might have a quick answer, but there seems to be a structural problem with your data that, if solved, could save you lots of time and problems in the future.

Comment: Hi Florian! I edited that there are a lot of columns and there are many time series which I didn't show in my example. They have different time ranges and dates. So I made a lot of dataframes to overview the data. But you are right, if there were just a few stocks it would be better to put all in one dataframe.

Comment: When removing StockA entries in tableA, your database structure requires you to remove RollingSum entries in tableB. This is typically known as an deletion error in the world of databases. If, as you say, your database is extensive, it may be too late to change it now. But for future databases, you should look at Normal Forms: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFQaEYEc8_8&t=1221s Structuring your data with the 3rd normal form is ideal because when you update a field, it doesn't require updates somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

[image]

```
tableB = tableB.mask(~tableA.notna())
display(tableB)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `isin`

```
empty_index = df_stock.loc[df_stock['Stock A'].isna(), 'Index']
df_rolling_sum.loc[df_rolling_sum['Index'].isin(empty_index), 'Rolling Sum'] = np.nan
```

Comment: Thank you SomeDude!But how can I adapt that to a whole dataframe with hundreds of columns?If I try to change your solution I get an 'Cannot index with multidimensional key' error

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example with multiindex.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to you for your advices, the video and your patience. I hope one day I will be able to help someone else.

Unfortunetly that is not what will work for me, because the way you did it is column related.I have hundreds of columns (and thousands of rows) that need to be changed that way.To call each column particulary would cost an imense amount of time I think.

I put down a maybe better example.

```
import pandas as pd

tableA = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    date= ['2022-12-10', '2022-12-11', '2022-12-12', '2022-12-13', '2022-12-14', '2022-12-15'],
    StockA=[23, 25, 21, None, None, None],
    StockB=[104, 99, None, None, None, None],
    StockC=[38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44],
    StockD=[230, 251, 219, 219, None, None],
    StockE=[None, None, None, None, None, None]))

tableB = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    date= ['2022-12-10', '2022-12-11', '2022-12-12', '2022-12-13', '2022-12-14', '2022-12-15'],
    StockA=[0.45, 0.55, 0.51, 0.49, 0.48, 0.47],
    StockB=[0.23, 0.43, 0.56, 0.34, 0.66, 0.23],
    StockC=[0.12, 0.14, 0.13, 0.11, 0.15, 0.17],
    StockD=[0.22, 0.20, 0.24, 0.25, 0.27, 0.23],
    StockE=[0.70, 0.68, None, None, None, None],))

tableA.set_index('date', inplace = True)
tableB.set_index('date', inplace = True)

display(tableA,tableB)
```

the goal is something like this

[image]

your step with
no_price = tableA.price.isna()
and in my case
no_price = tableA.isna()

sounds good. But how can I go from here and take only values/cells from tableB that are False in the no_price dataframe?
I hope I made it easier this time.

Comment: Please edit the question and post these details as update.

Answer (score -1):

Given the input data:

```
import pandas as pd

tableA = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    date= ['2022-12-10', '2022-12-11', '2022-12-12', '2022-12-13', '2022-12-14', '2022-12-15'],
    price=[23, 25, 21, None, None, None]))

tableB = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    date= ['2022-12-10', '2022-12-11', '2022-12-12', '2022-12-13', '2022-12-14', '2022-12-15'],
    rollingsum=[0.45, 0.55, 0.51, 0.49, 0.48, 0.47]))

display(tableA, tableB)
```

[image]

Select the dates you want to remove.

```
no_price = tableA.price.isna()
dates_to_remove = tableA[no_price].date
dates_to_remove
```

[image]

Now we remove the undesired.

```
import numpy as np
to_nan = tableB.date.isin(dates_to_remove)
tableB.loc[to_nan, 'rollingsum'] = np.nan
tableB
```

[image]

I made a step-by-step procedure to make it easy for beginners to follow.

Comment: If it solves your problem, come back in a few years when you are a pro and help the newbies. Remember, be extra nice on StackOverflow. ;)